# A good model for velocity(t) such that it asymptotically approaches a max value

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, models

In many cases a powered vehicle accelerates its fastest at lower speeds. Then as the speed increases, the acceleration approaches zero and the max velocity is approached. What differential equation should be used to model such motion.

Comment: Just set up Newton's 2nd law. You must include a constant friction driving the car forward (caused by the engine's torque on the wheels), as well as air drag. Air drag depends on speed, so here you differential equation will appear.

Answer (score 0):

This effect can arise through drag. For motor vehicles, air resistance imparts this drag. For example, viscosity dominated drag begets a [drag force that is proportional to the velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27s_law) of a body moving through it.

[Ram pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_pressure), which is independent of viscosity and arises simply because the car has to push the air out of the way, so that the car changes the air's momentum and, by Newton's third law, the air must thrust back on the car. This drag is proportional to the velocity squared, and dominates at car speeds. The $F\propto v^2$ is easy to see: $v$ is proportional to the mass rate at which the car interacts with the air, (twice as fast means it pushes twice the mass of air out of the way per unit time) and $v$ is also proportional to the momentum change imparted to each unit mass of air.

If you write differential equations for a body pushed by a constant force $F$ in such mediums:

$$F- \lambda_r\,\dot{x}^2-\lambda_v\,\dot{x} = m\,\ddot{x}$$

where $\lambda_r$ and $\lambda_v$ are the co-efficients of ram and viscous drag respectively, you'll easily reproduce the behavior you want. Indeed, the behavior can be deduced without solving the differential equation.